# How to Check If data is Present or not Then delete the data

Tags: c#, mysql

I want that when someone want to delete the data from database .first it checj whether the data is present or not if data is not present in database it show that no record found so how i canh do that

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter ID card No or Phone No to Delete");
        Double inputt = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        conn_string.Server = "localhost";
        conn_string.UserID = "root";
        conn_string.Password = "DynaSoft123@";
        conn_string.Database = "directory";

        string Query = "delete from directory.userdata where IdCardNo='" + inputt + "';";

        MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString());
        MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2);

        MySqlDataReader MyReader2;
        MyConn2.Open();
        MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Deleted Successfully...");
```

Comment: Use MyCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery(). this will returns the number of rows affected. if ==0 then you can show "No record found"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ExecuteNonQuery`, not `ExecuteReader()`. You don't have to check if data exist, if not `delete` just do nothing.

```
...
//DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
using (MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString())) {
  MyConn2.Open();

  //DONE: make sql readable
  //DONE: make sql paramterized
  string Query = 
    @"delete 
        from directory.userdata 
       where IdCardNo = @prm_IdCardNo";

  using (MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2)) {
    //TODO: Add("@prm_IdCardNo", RDBMSType).Value = is a better option
    MyCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_IdCardNo", inputt);

    // ExecuteNonQuery - just execute, we have nothing to read
    int affected = MyCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // If you want to know if table has been modified
    if (affected > 0) {
      // Some records are affected (deleted)
    }
  } 
}
```